# Site is bricked; think it has to do with Contact Storage module

Tags: 8, entities, emails

I built a Drupal 8 site about a year ago and installed the "contact storage" module to keep a database of contact messages. Last week I upgraded Drupal core to 8.2.3. After the install I ran the update script and I had a pending update:

> **views module**
>
> • Fix views with serializer dependencies.

When I attempted to run the update, I received the following error message:

> **views module**
>
> Update serializer_dependencies
>
> Failed: Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The
>   "entity:contact_message" plugin does not exist. in
>   Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 52 of /core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).

I've tried two fresh installs with the same problem. From the best Googling I can do, I believe that the problem is related to the contact storage module I installed earlier. I believe that I may have patched a script to get it working, but at this point I honestly don't remember and I don't have any backups (lesson learned). Almost my entire site is "bricked" now because of this — the only pages I've found that load are the login page and the Extend page (but not the Uninstall tab).

Does anyone have any ideas as to what may be wrong and how to fix it? Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to drush? Running `drush entity-updates` might help

Comment: Trying to get drush access now. Will update.

Comment: Tried running `drush entity-updates` and received the following error:
`[error]  Command entity-updates needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.`

Comment: You need to run it from inside the docroot, or use -r {path/to/docroot}